# Is it possible to make a sound when using a splash screen in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a beginner in game making.

Is it possible to make a sound when splash screen?
Do you know the game "Clash Royale"or "Clash Of Clans" that Supercell made? 
When the game is opened, it makes sounds.
How can I do this?
Could you teach me?

*I am also a beginner in English, so I think that there is a mistake in English.←

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Only images can be added to Unity's splash screen system.

You will have to do it another way. Create an intro scene and make it to be the first scene to load from the Build Settings. Use Unity's `AudioSource` API to load and play the sound when this into scene loads. When the sound is done playing, load your game main scene.

Comment: Thank you for your early reply!It was very helpful.

Comment: Glad  I was able to help